# How do I receive more that 64 bytes with Arduino

Tags: serial, programming, c++

I am using QtSerialPort to send and receive data from Arduino. I am sending **more than 64 bytes** (125, 220, more), I receive the data with Arduino, and trying to sending back the same data, but Arduino **sending only 64 bytes** in its response. Then I am thinking that the problem is with Arduino buffer. I am trying to clear the data but without result.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
void loop() {    
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        delay(500);
        int size = Serial.available();
        while (i < size)
            buffer[i++] = Serial.read();

        Serial.print(buffer);
        //delay(500);
        int j = 0;
        while (j < size)
            buffer[j++] = '\0';
        //while (Serial.available()) Serial.read(); I tried it
        //Serial.flush();   Also tried it, but nothing.             
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably also sending the zeros back, hard to guess how that will confuse QT.  It will.  Just no point to using a buffer, just read one byte and send it back with Serial.write().

Comment: Remove the `delay(500)`: during this delay, you are letting the internal buffer of `Serial` overflow. Instead of just wasting 500 ms, you should be copying the incoming data into your own `buffer` array as it comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of blocking the loop for 500 ms, you should be actively
reading the data as it comes. Otherwise the internal buffer of the
`Serial` object will overflow after only 64 bytes are received.

Here is an example that copies the incoming bytes into a larger buffer
(256 bytes) and, upon receiving an end-of-line character, echoes
back the whole line.

```c++
void loop() {
    static char buffer[256];
    static size_t pos;              // position of next write

    while (Serial.available() && pos < sizeof buffer - 1) {

        // Read incoming byte.
        char c = Serial.read();
        buffer[pos++] = c;

        // Echo received message.
        if (c == '\n') {            // \n means "end of message"
            buffer[pos] = '\0';     // terminate the buffer
            Serial.print(buffer);   // send echo
            pos = 0;                // reset to start of buffer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after every read action the buffer consume one character and the buffer size is menor? So if I constantly send data to  Arduino and constantly read from buffer, the buffer never going to be on overloaded?

Comment: Did not really understand your question. There are two buffers: the one from the Serial object (64 bytes), and your application's buffer. Which one are you talking about? At 9600 bps, each byte takes about one millisecond, which is plenty. As long as `loop()` runs often enough (with no `delay()`), the Serial buffer is not going to overflow.

Comment: The final result was receive each byte one by one and removed any delay in the code. Thank you @Edgar Bonet